# Is it possible for ubuntu to change user itself

Tags: username, accounts

I was streaming data from Twitter and let my laptop open at night. In the morning, i saw that Ubuntu is open with Guest user not my user account. I wondered how can it be. Is it possible for ubuntu to change user itself or what do you think? Some hacking can be? Because surely while streaming data from Twitter, some ports are open. Any idea my friends?

Comment: It is hardly possible to take over a system from the guest account, so I doubt that an attack would have aimed at this if your normal account was logged in. Do you have pets or any other people in your household? Probably one of them stepping on the keyboard is a more likely explanation.

Comment: Thank you for answer but i dont have any pet. My own user account was open at night.